# JavaFx lineChart Zoom by CategoryAxis (String Type)

Tags: java, javafx

i would mouse movement to linechart zoom xAxis 、yAxis(yAxis is NumberAxis,xAxis is categoryAxis.)
I am here search the one method,This method NumberAxis zoom is No problem,but categoryAxis zoom have problem.
How to do this?
Thanks all.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Zoom extends Application {
Path path;//Add path for freehand
Rectangle rect;
SimpleDoubleProperty rectinitX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
SimpleDoubleProperty rectinitY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
SimpleDoubleProperty rectX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
SimpleDoubleProperty rectY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
LineChart lineChart2 =null;
double initXLowerBound = 0, initXUpperBound = 0, initYLowerBound = 0, initYUpperBound = 0;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    stage.setTitle("Lines plot");  
    StackPane Mainpane = new StackPane();
    Mainpane.getChildren().add(addMainpane());
    Scene scene = new Scene(Mainpane, 800, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene);        
    path = new Path();
    path.setStrokeWidth(1);
    path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    stage.show();
}
private StackPane addMainpane(){

    StackPane Mainpane = new StackPane();

    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 13, 1);


    final LineChart lineChart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);

    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-01", 1));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-02", 2));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-03", 3));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-04", 4));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-05", 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-06", 6));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-07", 7));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-08", 8));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-09", 9));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-10", 10));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-11", 11));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-12", 12));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-13", 1));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-14", 2));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-15", 3));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-16", 4));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-17", 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-18", 6));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-19", 7));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-20", 8));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-21", 9));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-22", 10));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-23", 11));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-24", 12));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-25", 1));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-26", 2));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-27", 3));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-28", 4));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-29", 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2013-04-30", 6));


    //initXLowerBound = ((CategoryAxis) lineChart.getXAxis()).getLowerBound();
    //initXUpperBound = ((CategoryAxis) lineChart.getXAxis()).getUpperBound();
    initYLowerBound = ((NumberAxis) lineChart.getYAxis()).getLowerBound();
    initYUpperBound = ((NumberAxis) lineChart.getYAxis()).getUpperBound();
    System.out.println("initXLowerBound:"+initXLowerBound);

    BorderPane pane;
    pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(addpane(lineChart));
    Mainpane.getChildren().add(pane);
    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1);
    lineChart2 = lineChart;

    pane.setOnMouseClicked(mouseHandler);
    pane.setOnMouseDragged(mouseHandler);
    pane.setOnMouseEntered(mouseHandler);
    pane.setOnMouseExited(mouseHandler);
    pane.setOnMouseMoved(mouseHandler);
    pane.setOnMousePressed(mouseHandler);
    pane.setOnMouseReleased(mouseHandler);

    rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.setFill(Color.web("blue", 0.1));
    rect.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    rect.setStrokeDashOffset(50);

    rect.widthProperty().bind(rectX.subtract(rectinitX));
    rect.heightProperty().bind(rectY.subtract(rectinitY));
    pane.getChildren().add(rect);

    return Mainpane;
}
 private StackPane addpane(LineChart lineChart){

    StackPane Subpane = new StackPane();
    Subpane.getChildren().add(lineChart);
    return Subpane;
}

EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    if (mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
        if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
            rect.setX(mouseEvent.getX());
            rect.setY(mouseEvent.getY());
            rectinitX.set(mouseEvent.getX());
            rectinitY.set(mouseEvent.getY());
            System.out.println("rect:"+rect);
        } else if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
            rectX.set(mouseEvent.getX());
            rectY.set(mouseEvent.getY());
        } else if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED) {

            if ((rectinitX.get() >= rectX.get()) && (rectinitY.get() >= rectY.get())) {
                //Condizioni Iniziali
                LineChart lineChart = lineChart2;

               // ((CategoryAxis) lineChart.getXAxis()).setLowerBound(initXLowerBound);
                //((CategoryAxis) lineChart.getXAxis()).setUpperBound(initXUpperBound);

                ((NumberAxis) lineChart.getYAxis()).setLowerBound(initYLowerBound);
                ((NumberAxis) lineChart.getYAxis()).setUpperBound(initYUpperBound);



            } else {
                //Zoom In

                double Tgap = 0;
                double newLowerBound, newUpperBound, axisShift;
                double xScaleFactor, yScaleFactor;
                double xaxisShift, yaxisShift;                  
                LineChart  lineChart = lineChart2;

                // Zoom in Y-axis by changing bound range.            
                NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) lineChart.getYAxis();
                Tgap = yAxis.getHeight()/(yAxis.getUpperBound() - yAxis.getLowerBound());
                axisShift = getSceneShiftY(yAxis);
                yaxisShift = axisShift;
                System.out.println("yAxisUPPER:"+yAxis.getUpperBound()+"yAxisLOWER:"+ yAxis.getLowerBound());
                newUpperBound = yAxis.getUpperBound() - ((rectinitY.get() - axisShift) / Tgap);
                newLowerBound = yAxis.getUpperBound() - (( rectY.get() - axisShift) / Tgap);

                if (newUpperBound > yAxis.getUpperBound())
                    newUpperBound = yAxis.getUpperBound();

                yScaleFactor = (yAxis.getUpperBound() - yAxis.getLowerBound())/(newUpperBound - newLowerBound);
                yAxis.setLowerBound(newLowerBound);
                yAxis.setUpperBound(newUpperBound);

                /*XYChart.Series series1 = (Series) lineChart.getData().get(0);
                if (!series1.getData().isEmpty()) {
                    series1.getData().remove(0);
                    series1.getData().remove(series1.getData().size() - 1);
                }*/

               // CategoryAxis xAxis = (CategoryAxis) lineChart.getXAxis();

            }
            // Hide the rectangle
            rectX.set(0);
            rectY.set(0);
        }
    }// end if (mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY)

}
};

private static double getSceneShiftX(Node node) {
    double shift = 0;
    do { 
        shift += node.getLayoutX(); 
        node = node.getParent();
    } while (node != null);
    return shift;
}

private static double getSceneShiftY(Node node) {
    double shift = 0;
    do { 
        shift += node.getLayoutY(); 
        node = node.getParent();
    } while (node != null);
    return shift;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.you first need to download and add to you project the DateAxis class from [here](http://myjavafx.blogspot.co.il/2013/09/javafx-charts-display-date-values-on.html)
then use this code (same data as yours), cheeked it, it works.

```
import java.util.Date;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DateLineChartTest extends Application {
Path path;//Add path for freehand
Rectangle rect;
SimpleDoubleProperty rectinitX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
SimpleDoubleProperty rectinitY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
SimpleDoubleProperty rectX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
SimpleDoubleProperty rectY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
LineChart lineChart2 =null;
Date initXLowerBound =new Date(2013-1900,4,1);
 Date  initXUpperBound =new Date(2013-1900,4,30);
double initYLowerBound , initYUpperBound;
 DateAxis xAxis;
 NumberAxis yAxis;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    stage.setTitle("Lines plot");  
    StackPane Mainpane = new StackPane();
    Mainpane.getChildren().add(addMainpane());
    Scene scene = new Scene(Mainpane, 800, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene);        
    path = new Path();
    path.setStrokeWidth(1);
    path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    stage.show();
}
private StackPane addMainpane(){

    StackPane Mainpane = new StackPane();

    final DateAxis xAxis = new DateAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 13, 1);


    final LineChart lineChart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);

    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,1), 1));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,2), 2));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,3), 3));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,4), 4));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,5), 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,6), 6));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,7), 7));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,8), 8));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,9), 9));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,10), 10));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,11), 11));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,12), 12));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,13), 1));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,14), 2));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,15), 3));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,16), 4));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,17), 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,18), 6));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,19), 7));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,20), 8));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,21), 9));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,22), 10));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,23), 11));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,24), 12));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,25), 1));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,26), 2));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,27), 3));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,28), 4));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,29), 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(new Date(2013-1900,4,30), 6));


    initXLowerBound = xAxis.getLowerBound();
    initXUpperBound = xAxis.getUpperBound();
    initYLowerBound = ((NumberAxis) lineChart.getYAxis()).getLowerBound();
    initYUpperBound = ((NumberAxis) lineChart.getYAxis()).getUpperBound();
    System.out.println("initXLowerBound:"+initXLowerBound);

    BorderPane pane;
    pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(addpane(lineChart));
    Mainpane.getChildren().add(pane);
    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1);
    lineChart2 = lineChart;

    pane.setOnMouseClicked(mouseHandler);
    pane.setOnMouseDragged(mouseHandler);
    pane.setOnMouseEntered(mouseHandler);
    pane.setOnMouseExited(mouseHandler);
    pane.setOnMouseMoved(mouseHandler);
    pane.setOnMousePressed(mouseHandler);
    pane.setOnMouseReleased(mouseHandler);

    rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.setFill(Color.web("blue", 0.1));
    rect.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    rect.setStrokeDashOffset(50);

    rect.widthProperty().bind(rectX.subtract(rectinitX));
    rect.heightProperty().bind(rectY.subtract(rectinitY));
    pane.getChildren().add(rect);

    return Mainpane;
}
 private StackPane addpane(LineChart lineChart){

    StackPane Subpane = new StackPane();
    Subpane.getChildren().add(lineChart);
    return Subpane;
}

EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    if (mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
        if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
            rect.setX(mouseEvent.getX());
            rect.setY(mouseEvent.getY());
            rectinitX.set(mouseEvent.getX());
            rectinitY.set(mouseEvent.getY());
            System.out.println("rect:"+rect);
        } else if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
            rectX.set(mouseEvent.getX());
            rectY.set(mouseEvent.getY());
        } else if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED) {

            if ((rectinitX.get() >= rectX.get()) && (rectinitY.get() >= rectY.get())) {
                //Condizioni Iniziali
                LineChart lineChart = lineChart2;

               xAxis.setLowerBound(initXLowerBound);
                xAxis.setUpperBound(initXUpperBound);

                ((NumberAxis) lineChart.getYAxis()).setLowerBound(initYLowerBound);
                ((NumberAxis) lineChart.getYAxis()).setUpperBound(initYUpperBound);



            } else {
                //Zoom In

                double Tgap = 0;
                double newLowerBound, newUpperBound, axisShift;
                double xScaleFactor, yScaleFactor;
                double xaxisShift, yaxisShift;                  
                LineChart  lineChart = lineChart2;

                // Zoom in Y-axis by changing bound range.            
                NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) lineChart.getYAxis();
                Tgap = yAxis.getHeight()/(yAxis.getUpperBound() - yAxis.getLowerBound());
                axisShift = getSceneShiftY(yAxis);
                yaxisShift = axisShift;
                System.out.println("yAxisUPPER:"+yAxis.getUpperBound()+"yAxisLOWER:"+ yAxis.getLowerBound());
                newUpperBound = yAxis.getUpperBound() - ((rectinitY.get() - axisShift) / Tgap);
                newLowerBound = yAxis.getUpperBound() - (( rectY.get() - axisShift) / Tgap);

                if (newUpperBound > yAxis.getUpperBound())
                    newUpperBound = yAxis.getUpperBound();

                yScaleFactor = (yAxis.getUpperBound() - yAxis.getLowerBound())/(newUpperBound - newLowerBound);
                yAxis.setLowerBound(newLowerBound);
                yAxis.setUpperBound(newUpperBound);

               XYChart.Series series1 = (Series) lineChart.getData().get(0);
                if (!series1.getData().isEmpty()) {
                    series1.getData().remove(0);
                    series1.getData().remove(series1.getData().size() - 1);
                }

                DateAxis xAxis = (DateAxis) lineChart.getXAxis();

            }
            // Hide the rectangle
            rectX.set(0);
            rectY.set(0);
        }
    }// end if (mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY)

}
};

private static double getSceneShiftX(Node node) {
    double shift = 0;
    do { 
        shift += node.getLayoutX(); 
        node = node.getParent();
    } while (node != null);
    return shift;
}

private static double getSceneShiftY(Node node) {
    double shift = 0;
    do { 
        shift += node.getLayoutY(); 
        node = node.getParent();
    } while (node != null);
    return shift;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```